# puppet error with sed command to change content in jail.conf?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sed, puppet

code:

```
exec { "fail2banadd": <br>  
  command => '/bin/sed  -i "/\[ssh\]/,/\[dropbear\]/ s/maxretry = 6/maxretry = 5/" /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf',<br>
}<br>
```

Error:

```
=> default: err: /Stage[main]//Exec[fail2banadd]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /bin/sed -i "/[ssh]/,/[dropbear]/ s/maxretry = 6/maxretry = 5/" /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf returned 2 inste d of one of [0] at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/manifests/init.pp:76
```

Now output.

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6

[dropbear]

enabled  = false
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/dropbear
maxretry = 6
```

Want this output.

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6

[dropbear]

enabled  = false
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/dropbear
maxretry = 5
```

Comment: Maybe sed can't find `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`, and so returned a failure code of `2`.Also, it seems that your code is selecting the wrong lines if you want to change the `maxretry` *outside* of the lines from `[ssh]` to `[dropbear]`.

Comment: Can you tell me?How to solve this?

Comment: Did you notice that Puppet eliminated the backslashes from your manifest? `sed` receives plain brackets, so your expressions become character classes. I think the approach is terrible. Have you looked at augeas? An inifile lense should get you there.

Comment: You're trying to change an INI style file.  You should use the 'inifile' module.  In Puppet Enterprise 2017, I had to add the module.  In PE 2019 the module is already present.

Answer (score 0):

ooga is correct in saying that your current code changes the `maxretry` between `ssh` and `dropbear`. If you want the `maxretry` outside of `ssh` and `dropbear` use:
`sed '/\[ssh\]/,/\[dropbear\]/ !s/maxretry = 6/maxretry = 5/'`
The `!` inverts the range to be everything outside of `ssh` and `dropbear`. As for the error, I'm going to have to agree with ooga that `sed` is having trouble finding the file. Running

```
    [user@host]# sed 's///' badfile.txt
    sed: can't read badfile.txt: No such file or directory
    [user@host]# echo $?
    2
```

Showing that the error code of 2 is likely due to a bad path. However after creating the file and changing the permission you can see,

```
    [user@host]$ sed 's///' badfile.txt 
    sed: can't read badfile.txt: Permission denied
    [user@host]$ echo $?
    2
```

So it could also be a permissions error. So I would make sure that
1.`/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` exists
2. you have read permissions on it.